# Stop processing request and redirect to file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hi i have mvc2 application where i want to stop processing application when settings file is set to offline and display offline page to the user.

i have decided to create in global.asax.cs switch that will check it web application is offline and pending result it will redirect to offline page or continue with processing page.

**how ever when i try to run it with this code i get error:**

> Server Error in '/' Application. Response is not available in this
>   context. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Response is not available
>   in this context.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 25:             if (!this.IsApplicationOnline()) Line 26:
>   { Line 27:                 Response.Redirect("~/Content/offline.html",
>   true); Line 28:             } Line 29:             else
>
> Source File: *\Global.asax.cs    Line: 27
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Response is not available in this
>   context.]    System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Response() +3002456
>   easyccms.WebUI.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   *Global.asax.cs:27

**My code is as follows**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            if (!this.IsApplicationOnline())
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Content/offline.html", true);
            }
            else
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i have found a solution.

I had to specify which response it is and therefore: added System.Web.HttpContext.Current

and this works. Now i just presume there can be more then httpcontext

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Content/offline.html", true);
```